# Event Data not flowing from Google Tag Manager to Google Analytics for a particular subdomain

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Issue Summary: Event Data not flowing from Google Tag Manager to Google Analytics for a particular subdomain (was working earlier and stopped suddenly)

Description:

I am explaining the setup first so that the issue can be understood and be of help in finding the solution to this problem.

Setup:

1. We have a website (say XXXXX.com) built in wordpress and a web application on its subdomain (app.XXXXX.com) hosted on AWS. We need data for both of these to be tracked in Google Analytics.
2. We have installed the Google Tag Manager code in the head and body section of the website and the app so that both of these are connected to Google Tag Manager.
3. We then created a Configuration Tag in Google Tag Manager to connect it to GA4 property of analytics.
4. Next we created Tags for the button clicks we want to track in Google Tag Manager on it we have selected the proper Configuration Tag to be able to send the data to GA4, given proper event names, added proper triggers (URL Contains and Click Text equals) and then tested that the Tags are firing using Tag Assistant.
5. We then verified in GA4 property that the events created for both the website (XXXXX.com) and app (app.XXXXX.com) are showing up.

This Setup was all working fine for a few months and nothing was changed in between then and now.

Issue: All event data was being sent to GA4 property for a couple of months. Now suddenly the events from app (app.XXXXX.com) have stopped showing up in GA4 property but all the events from website (XXXXX.com) still show in GA4 property. The event data for the subdomain app.xxxxx.com not flowing to Analytics is the problem we need help with.

Troubleshooting Already done:

1. We used Chrome Developer interface to check if the Google Tag Manager script is running or not and we see the Status codes (200 and 204) which indicate the script is running ( on app.XXXXX.com)

[Chrome Developer interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3b8h.png)

2. Next we tested the Tag and event are firing or not using the Tag Assistant and see that the event is actually firing

[Tag Assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHZuO.png)

3. Next we checked using the real time feature in Google Analytics GA4 property to see if the events are flowing to Analytics or not. The result is that All the events from website (XXXXX.com) still show in GA4 property. The event data for the subdomain app.xxxxx.com not flowing to Analytics is the problem we need help with.

Help requested:
Any help on how to troubleshoot this further or how to fix this issue will be highly appreciated.

We also could not find a way to reach support from google on this and if there is a way to reach google for this then please let us know.

Thank You!

Comment: For your setup, are you using two different streams (one for main domain, one for sub)? Or are you using the same measurement ID for each?

Answer (score 0):

- In Google Tag Manager make sure that the configuration tag does NOT have a field `debug_mode` set to any value.
- debug values will be sent and they show up in the real time interface but will never show up in the actual reports